# fabric.js loadFromJSON of Subclass from Textbox doesn't work

Tags: textbox, fabricjs, subclass

I created a subclass based on fabric.Textbox but can't make the loadFromJSON work on it. It results in `"caught TypeError: t.split is not a function"`.

Here is my code:

```
fabric.TextboxSubclass = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Textbox, {
    type: 'TextboxSubclass',

    toObject: function () {
        return fabric.util.object.extend(this.callSuper('toObject'), {});
    },
});

fabric.TextboxSubclass.fromObject = function (object, callback) {
    return fabric.Object._fromObject('TextboxSubclass', object, callback);
};

var textfield = new fabric.TextboxSubclass('load from JSON', {});
designer_canvas.add(textfield);
```

What i'm missing here?